# how to assign $scope variable with json string

Tags: angularjs, json

In AngularJs , the following is working -

```
$scope.product= {items:[{itemname:'apple',itemdesc:'fruit'}]}
```

But I want to get `$scope.product` from json string as below -

```
var strJson = "{items:[{itemname:'apple',itemdesc:'fruit'}]}";
$scope.product=strJson;
```

is not working. All I have is a json string and I need to assign to `$scope.product`. I have used `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.toJson()`, but they are not working.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Below is my exact code :

```
$http.get('/getItems').success(function(data) {
    var jsondata="{\items\:";
    jsondata+=JSON.stringify(data);
    jsondata+="}";
    jsondata=jsondata.replace(/"itemname"/g, 'itemname');
    jsondata=jsondata.replace(/"itemdesc"/g, 'itemdesc');

        // WORKING CODE
    $scope.product = {items:[{itemname:"apple",itemdesc:"fruit"}]}; 

        // NOT WORKING CODE
    var jsonObj = jsondata; 
    $scope.product = jsonObj;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

[JSON standard](http://www.json.org/) expects values to have **double quotes** around it. So your JSON string isn't parsable JSON.

```js
var mystr = '{"items": [{"itemname": "apple","itemdesc": "fruit"}]}';
console.log(JSON.parse(mystr))
console.log(typeof JSON.parse(mystr))
```

Comment: $http.get('/getItems').success(function(data) {
 var jsondata="{\items\:";
 jsondata+=JSON.stringify(data);
 jsondata+="}";
 jsondata=jsondata.replace(/"itemname"/g, 'itemname');
 jsondata=jsondata.replace(/"itemdesc"/g, 'itemdesc');
 
  // WORKING CODE
 $scope.product = {items:[{itemname:"apple",itemdesc:"fruit"}]}; 
    
  // NOT WORKING CODE
 var jsonObj = jsondata; 
 $scope.product = jsonObj;
});

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem. apparently, if you are using JSON.parse to convert a JSON string to JSON then your property names should be wrapped with double quotes instead of single quotes.

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.product= '{"items":[{"itemname":"apple","itemdesc":"fruit"}]}'
    $scope.product = JSON.parse($scope.product);
    
console.log($scope.product)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 
</div>
```

Comment: I just edited the answer. hope the downvoter will review this

Comment: Myexact problem is this : $http.get('/getItems').success(function(data) {
 var jsondata="{\items\:";
 jsondata+=JSON.stringify(data);
 jsondata+="}";
 jsondata=jsondata.replace(/"itemname"/g, 'itemname');
 jsondata=jsondata.replace(/"itemdesc"/g, 'itemdesc');
 
  // WORKING CODE
 $scope.product = {items:[{itemname:"apple",itemdesc:"fruit"}]}; 
    
  // NOT WORKING CODE
 var jsonObj = jsondata; 
 $scope.product = jsonObj;
});

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use angular way to conver json to object:

```
$scope.product= "{items:[{itemname:'apple',itemdesc:'fruit'}]}";
$scope.product = angular.fromJson($scope.product);
```

And object to json as follow:

```
var strJson = angular.toJson($scope.product);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.parse, find the answer below

`var strJson = JSON.parse("{items:[{itemname:'apple',itemdesc:'fruit'}]}")`;

Answer (score 0):

I think your string format is not correct, it should be like this.

```
var str = '{"items":[{"itemname":"apple","itemdesc":"fruit"}]}';
$scope.product = JSON.parse(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

please use double quotes in the JSON (by escaping them). Then JSON.parse() will accept the input string appropriately and parse correctly. Also remove square brackets.

```
$scope.jsonString = "{\"items\":{\"itemname\":\"apple\",\"itemdesc\":\"fruit\"}}";

var test = JSON.parse($scope.jsonString);
```

on a side note you can also use [JSON Lint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) to check if your JSON is valid.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: your parent node 'items' in the line - `var jsondata="{\items\:";` does not contain double quotes. please try `var jsondata="{\"items\":";`. Also please check subsequent values to place double quotes. There is the escaping '\' character but not the character you will be escaping.

Comment: Please read the question once more.     $scope.product = {items:[{itemname:"apple",itemdesc:"fruit"}]}; 
is working code

Comment: Your object works fine I get it. I was talking about the json 'STRING'  which is giving you parsing errors - and which is your requirement am i correct ? The double quotes at the right places should solve the issue of parsing it. I tried it using `JSON.parse()` and it seems to be working fine. Let me know if I am missing something.